# Loop through XML and move particular child element in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have to loop through the "Claim" elements and move the "OrderClosed" element so that it is *after* the "OrderDate".

So it has to be "OrderDate" *then* "OrderClosed" right after.

Sadly due to how this works I have to move these elements after the XML is already created. 3rd party will not accept the XML until elements are in the right order.

```
<Order>
    <Header>
        <SenderName>Tim</SenderName>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Claim>
            <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
            <OrderClosed>2023-12-09</OrderClosed>
            <OrderDate>2023-12-07</OrderDate>
            <Service>
                <Operation>Order</Operation>
            </Service>
        </Claim>
        <Claim>
            <OrderNumber>67891</OrderNumber>
            <OrderClosed>2023-12-05</OrderClosed>
            <OrderDate>2023-12-04</OrderDate>
            <Service>
                <Operation>Order</Operation>
            </Service>
        </Claim>
    </Body>
</Order>
```

I've been trying to use XDocument or XmlDocument to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: As already stated, I do not know how to do this, hence nothing to reproduce and no code to show. I provided the XML and I'm asking how to achieve a result I've clearly stated.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `<OrderDate>` and `<OrderClosed>` always have a parent and that `<OrderDate>` is always a next sibling of `<OrderClosed>`

```cs
var filePath = "/path";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);

var orderClosedElements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("OrderClosed");

foreach (var item in orderClosedElements.Cast<XmlNode>().ToList())
{
    if(item.NextSibling?.Name == "OrderDate")
    {
        var orderDate = item.NextSibling;
        orderDate.ParentNode!.RemoveChild(item);
        orderDate.ParentNode.InsertAfter(item, orderDate);
    }
}

doc.Save(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the below example using `XmlDocument` to accomplish this task.

```
string xml = @"<Order>
                <Header>
                    <SenderName>Tim</SenderName>
                </Header>
                <Body>
                    <Claim>
                        <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
                        <OrderClosed>2023-12-09</OrderClosed>
                        <OrderDate>2023-12-07</OrderDate>
                        <Service>
                            <Operation>Order</Operation>
                        </Service>
                    </Claim>
                    <Claim>
                        <OrderNumber>67891</OrderNumber>
                        <OrderClosed>2023-12-05</OrderClosed>
                        <OrderDate>2023-12-04</OrderDate>
                        <Service>
                            <Operation>Order</Operation>
                        </Service>
                    </Claim>
                </Body>
            </Order>";

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
XmlNodeList claimNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Claim");

foreach (XmlNode claimNode in claimNodes)
{
    XmlNode orderClosedNode = claimNode.SelectSingleNode("OrderClosed");
    XmlNode orderDateNode = claimNode.SelectSingleNode("OrderDate");

    if (orderClosedNode != null && orderDateNode != null)
    {
        claimNode.InsertAfter(orderClosedNode, orderDateNode);
    }
}

string modifiedXml = xmlDoc.OuterXml;
Console.WriteLine(modifiedXml);
```

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FvOZLP).

Answer (score 0):

XSLT based solution.

**Input XML**

```
<Order>
    <Header>
        <SenderName>Tim</SenderName>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Claim>
            <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
            <OrderClosed>2023-12-09</OrderClosed>
            <OrderDate>2023-12-07</OrderDate>
            <Service>
                <Operation>Order</Operation>
            </Service>
        </Claim>
        <Claim>
            <OrderNumber>67891</OrderNumber>
            <OrderClosed>2023-12-05</OrderClosed>
            <OrderDate>2023-12-04</OrderDate>
            <Service>
                <Operation>Order</Operation>
            </Service>
        </Claim>
    </Body>
</Order>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderClosed"/>

    <!--switch seqiential order of XML elements-->
    <xsl:template match="OrderDate">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../OrderClosed"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<Order>
  <Header>
    <SenderName>Tim</SenderName>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Claim>
      <OrderNumber>12345</OrderNumber>
      <OrderDate>2023-12-07</OrderDate>
      <OrderClosed>2023-12-09</OrderClosed>
      <Service>
        <Operation>Order</Operation>
      </Service>
    </Claim>
    <Claim>
      <OrderNumber>67891</OrderNumber>
      <OrderDate>2023-12-04</OrderDate>
      <OrderClosed>2023-12-05</OrderClosed>
      <Service>
        <Operation>Order</Operation>
      </Service>
    </Claim>
  </Body>
</Order>
```